# Is Uniqueness of Lagrange Multipliers required for Projected Hessian?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am reading through Chapter 12 of "Numerical Optimization" by Nocedal and Wright, in which Sufficient Second-Order conditions for local optima in constrained optimisation are discussed. They describe the Sufficient Second-Order Condition as follows

> Theorem 12.6 - Suppose that for some feasible point $x^{*} \in \mathbb{R}$ there is a
>   Lagrange multiplier vector $\lambda^{*}$ such that the KKT conditions
>   are satisfied. Suppose also that
>
> $$w^{T}\nabla^{2}_{xx}\mathcal{L}(x^{*}, \lambda^{*})w > 0, \quad
> \forall w \in \mathcal{C}(x^{*}, \lambda^{*}), \: w \neq 0 $$
>
> Then $x^{*}$ is a strict local solution of the corresponding optimisation problem.

Where $\mathcal{C}(x^{*}, \lambda^{*})$ is defined as follows

> We define the Critical Cone as follows:
>
> $w \in C(x^{*}, \lambda^{*})$ if and only if
>
> 1. $\nabla c_{i}(x^{*})^{T}w = 0 \quad \forall i \in \mathcal{E}$
> 2. $\nabla c_{i}(x^{*})^{T}w = 0 \quad \forall i \in \mathcal{A}(x^{*})\cap\mathcal{I} \text{ with }\lambda_{i}^{*} > 0$
> 3. $\nabla c_{i}(x^{*})^{T}w \geq 0 \quad \forall i \in \mathcal{A}(x^{*})\cap\mathcal{I} \text{ with } \lambda_{i}^{*} = 0 $
>
> where $\mathcal{E}$ is the index set of equality constraints,
>   $\mathcal{I}$ is the index set of inequality constraints,
>   $\mathcal{A}(x^{*})$ is the index set of active constraints, and
>   $c_{i}$ is the constraint function corresponding to index $i$.

The authors discuss weaker versions of the second-order sufficient condition which rely on additional assumptions and correspond to a two-sided projection of the Hessian of the Lagrangian.

> The simplest case is obtained when the multiplier $\lambda^{*}$ that
>   satisfies the KKT conditions is unique and strict complementarity
>   holds. In this case, the definition of $\mathcal{C}(x^{*},
> \lambda^{*})$ reduces to
>
> $$\mathcal{C}(x^{*}, \lambda^{*}) = \text{Null }[\nabla
> c_{i}(x^{*})^{T}]_{i \in \mathcal{A}(x^{*})}$$

**Why is the uniqueness of the lagrange multiplier vector required here?** Doesn't the equivalence of the critical cone to the null space of the matrix of active constraint gradients follow from strict complementarity alone? If so, what is the benefit to having a unique vector of Lagrange multipliers?

**Perhaps the benefit of uniqueness comes later?** The authors use the above equivalence to show that the sufficient second-order condition can be restated as

$$u^{T}Z^{T}\nabla_{xx}^{2}\mathcal{L}(x^{*}, \lambda^{*})Zu \quad\text{is positive definite}$$

where $\mathcal{C}(x^{*}, \lambda^{*}) = \{ Zu \: | \: u \in \mathbb{R}^{|\mathcal{A}(x^{*})|}\}$. The authors claim that $Z$ can be found via QR decomposition of the matrix of active constraint gradients. **Does the uniqueness of the lagrange multiplier vector make this any easier?**